# iOS App: Youtube Embeds Overflow Completely

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, youtube

I know youtube embeds are sort of new, but just so you people in charge of iOS know, this is what a Youtube embed looks like on the app:

[image]

Comment: I hope you already recharged your iPhone.

Comment: I'm taking a look at this.

Answer (score 2):

Youtube embeds did need a bit of love.

This should now be fixed in **beta version 1.0.1.88.**

Comment: Congratulations, Stack Exchange, for having the fastest, mostly community-aware dev support in the industry.